# Median filter of a pgm image

Tags: java, arrays, median, pgm

I have to write a program that replaces each pixel with the median value of it and its 8 neighbors. What I have will compile but when i try to create a new image im getting multiple errors. Help is appreciated.

Here's the stacktrace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: [I cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable
at java.util.ComparableTimSort.countRunAndMakeAscending(ComparableTimSort.java:290)
at java.util.ComparableTimSort.sort(ComparableTimSort.java:171)
at java.util.ComparableTimSort.sort(ComparableTimSort.java:146)
at java.util.Arrays.sort(Arrays.java:472)
at ImageProcessing.median(ImageProcessing.java:25
```

And here's my code:

```
public static int [] [] median(int [] [] image) {
    int height = image.length;
    int width = image[0].length;
    int [] [] result = new int [height] [width];

    for (int col = 0 ; col < image.length ; col++) {
        result[0][col] = image[0][col];
        result[height - 1][col] = image[height - 1][col];
    }

    for (int row = 0 ; row < image[0].length ; row++) {
        result[row][0] = image[row][0];
        result[row][width - 1] = image[row][width - 1];
    }

    for (int row = 1 ; row < height - 1 ; row++) {
        for (int col = 1 ; col < width - 1 ; col++) {
            Arrays.sort(image);
            result[row][col] = image[row][col] / 2;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Please post what errors you are getting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you are getting is because in the last pair of loops, your call to `Arrays.sort(image)` is attempting to sort the rows of the image.

Instead of calling `Arrays.sort(image)`, you'll need to build up a list of the nine pixel values you want to look at (the pixel itself and its eight neighbors).  Then sort *that*, and write the median value to `result`.

Comment: How would I build a list?

Comment: I meant the words "build a list" loosely: you could either instantiate an [`ArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) and [`add`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#add(E)) the values to it, or instantiate a nine-element `int[]` array and populate it.  It's up to you.